# How durable is the MCU Captain America's bodysuit?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america

In the comics it seems to be little more than cloth, but in the movies it doesn't look like it's cloth. It looks tactical and practical, almost like modern day military gear. Is there any evidence of how durable it is?

Feats and evidence are prefered over words.

Answer (score 3):

[Captain America](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America)'s suit is composed of a Nomex and Kevlar fiber.  Possibly bulletproof and fireproof it can withstand blunt force trauma and energy blasts from alien weaponry.

His previous suit was made of carbon polymer and it offered a medium level of resistance to gunfire.

Comment: Can you find something other than an unsourced wikia passage as a reference?

Comment: @phantom42 Here's a whole page on it: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America's_Uniform and it has sources, Another : http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America%27s_Uniform

Comment: Both pages have sources for some things, but the MCU wikia has no citation for those facts you've mentioned, and the marvel wikia explicitly says "citation needed" for the same information.

Comment: @phantom42 His Stealth Uniform is made from bullet-proof nomex and kevlar but like you said no proper citations. [Geektyrant](http://geektyrant.com/news/the-evolution-of-captain-americas-uniform-ergt)  says the same thing but they probably got their info from the wikia.